# synced due to version name?

Tags: android

I was trying to copy a project from a computer to another,but when I import the project,gradle symced failed and said that:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[10,5]
Message: expected start or end tag
```

and [row,col]:[10,5] is this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.iperftest'
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

no matter how I tried ,it keep showing this error,what should I do to solve this problem? please help

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.iperftest">

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</manifest>
```

Actually I thought the error was at manifest,but android studio guide me to gradle,that's why i am confused

Comment: We need to see a bit more context from your `AndroidManifest.xml`. But this line would not normally appear in the manifest, looks more like to come from build.gradle

Comment: attach your manifest file

Comment: Actually I thought the error was at manifest,but android studio guide me to gradle,that's why i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is malformed in manifest. You have closed permission tag before ignoring protected permission.

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  //tag closed here
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />  // this will be considered new tag
```

Replace your code with below code.

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrectly placed
`tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"`

It needs to be inside the uses-permission tag.